# MUI: Is it possible to overwrite useAutocomplete's value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I am wondering if I can overwrite values in `useAutocomplete`.

I have multiple `CustomizedHook`s from MUI and each option are depended on parents like this.

[Massive Json File] => [CustomizedHook A] =filter=> [CustomizedHook B] =filter=>
[CustomizedHook C] =filter=>
[CustmizedHook D]

**Problem** 
When parent remove its option, children also remove the related options and values.
However, I could not remove the values. `useAutocomplete` seems not to allow to controll its value from outside.

**Specification**

- Use a massive JSON file as "options".
- Filter options from parent's selections
- Options and values should be related with each other.

**Sample JSON**

- Data amount : A < B < C < D

```
    [{
        "A": "OPTION_A",
        "B": "OPTION_B_1",
        "C": "OPTION_C_1",
        "D": "OPTION_D_1",
    },
    {
        "A": "OPTION_A",
        "B": "OPTION_B_2",
        "C": "OPTION_C_1",
        "D": "OPTION_D_1",
    },
    {
        "A": "OPTION_A",
        "B": "OPTION_B_3",
        "C": "OPTION_C_1",
        "D": "OPTION_D_1",
    },
    ...massive !
```

**FYI**

- useAutocomplete from MUI ( material-design-ui )
  https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#useautocomplete
- customizedHook from MUI ( material-design-ui )
  https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#customized-hook

Comment: What are CustomizedHooks? You speak of a parent, but don't explain what the parent is in your question. Is it the JSON? What do you mean "useAutocomplete seems not to allow to controll its value from outside"? Pass `useAutocomplete` a list of options using state or props. When state or props change, so will the autocomplete values.

Comment: Solution is: props -> filter -> memoize -> filter -> memoize -> filter -> memoize -> pass to `useAutocomplete`. If you don't use the intermediary values, don't memoize until the last step.

Comment: Here's the `CustmizedHook` from MUI . https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#customized-hook

Comment: This is the `useAutocomplete` form MUI. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#useautocomplete

Comment: I put the MUI tag back.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is not filterering but the original values inside useAutocomplete.

Comment: When I changed parent values, I wanna give changes to children's value. But not sure how to overwrite directly.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, which might be a sign that there isn't enough info in the question. Maybe you should add your code to the question. Why are you using multiple CustomizedHooks? Are you doing the filtering inside the CustomizedHooks? You should not be.

Comment: Try this: in the React component in which you pass the JSON to the component, do all of the filtering right away. You'll start with `options`, then [`useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to do your first filtering and create `optionsA`. `const optionsA = useMemo(() => options.filter(filter), [options])`. Adding `options` to the array as the second parameter makes it a dependency, meaning if `options` changes, so will `optionsA`. Then compute options B,C and D the same way. Then pass all of the options as props.

Comment: Thank you for your massages. I'm at a getaway so I'll add some codes when I get back home.

Comment: I think I'm doing the same way that you proposed. The problem I'm facing is this. 
If users narrow down the parent value while the child has already selected values, we may have to delete the child value depending on the parent's selection. So, I want to directly rewrite the value of child's useAutocomplete in order to erase the already selected value, but I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: This should not be a problem using the method I describe. If a value is changed in the parent, the memoized values will be recomputed and the autocompletes rerendered without the removed value. This is how React works. Please add a [minimally-reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ideally with a [Codesandbox](codesandbox.io)/[Codepen](https://codepen.io/).